# Using foundation data-abide can I still allow submit?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, zurb-foundation

I'm using [`data-abide`](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/forms.html) by [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs), and I love the way that it validates on the fly, and how it disables the submit for invalid form data.

However on a particular form, I want to keep the live validation, but still allow the form submit in a 'save progress' kind of deal which will skip validation so I can store progress.

If they click on 'save & submit' though, I'd like the validation to kick in.

So to recap, can I have two buttons on a form, one for 'save progress' which does not validate, and another 'save & submit' that does validate? If so, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Foundation but try just adding an additional regular button instead of a submit button.

```
<button type="button" id="saveAndGo">Save and Continue</button>
```

then when the button is clicked, just submit (assuming the form has an ID='myForm') or do the same processing as the regular valid form submission.

```
$("#saveAndGo").click(function() {
   $("#myForm" ).submit();
});
```

Now on the server side, you wont be able to tell if the submission is a valid or an invalid submission unless you add another hidden field on the form to note the difference.

```
__________________EDIT_________________
```

[Here is a working example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/vBza9kZ6uzUDiSdWHUvF?p=info)  Foundation does not check on a form submitted from JS.

Comment: Can't do that I'm afraid, the foundation validation kicks in on the form submit, whether that be from a button, hitting enter, or from JS

Comment: If Foundation will not let you submit an invalid form, then the only other option would be to copy the data from the form and create a jQuery http submit yourself.

Comment: Or what if you temporarily remove the data-abide attribute from the form tag then submit.  Afterwards, place the attribute back in.

Comment: A jquery form submission is my worst case fallback, but I'd like to avoid that so as not to introduce extra code for the sake of an ugly workaround.

Comment: Also, if I don't have the `data-abide` in the form in load, even if I put it in later it won't trigger validation, since JS will already have been parsed

Comment: My original answer seems to work fine. Foundation does not check on the Javascript form submission.  See the Plunker example I have attached to my original answer.

Comment: That plunker example doesn't have the foundation validation working for me, only HTML5 validation